How to properly Configure GridDB JDBC driver for connection using the fixed list method?
I'm trying to set up a GridDB JDBC connection using the fixed list method, but I'm encountering some issues. I've followed the documentation and added the necessary settings to the gs_cluster.json and gs_node.json files, but the connection still fails. Here are the steps I've taken so far:
Added the JDBC driver file to the class path
Class.forName("com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.sql.Driver");

Configured the connection URL:
Properties info = new Properties();
info.setProperty("user", "admin");
info.setProperty("password", "admin");
info.setProperty("applicationName", "MyApp");

Cluster definition file (gs_cluster.json):
{
    "cluster": {
        "clusterName": "myCluster",
        "replicationNum": 2,
        "heartbeatInterval": "5s",
        "loadbalanceCheckInterval": "180s",
        "notificationMember": [
            {
                "cluster": {"address": "192.168.0.10", "port":10010},
                "sync": {"address": "192.168.0.10", "port":10020},
                "system": {"address": "192.168.0.10", "port":10040},
                "transaction": {"address": "192.168.0.10", "port":10001},
                "sql": {"address": "192.168.0.10", "port":20001}
            },
            {
                "cluster": {"address": "192.168.0.11", "port":10010},
                "sync": {"address": "192.168.0.11", "port":10020},
                "system": {"address": "192.168.0.11", "port":10040},
                "transaction": {"address": "192.168.0.11", "port":10001},
                "sql": {"address": "192.168.0.11", "port":20001}
            },
            {
                "cluster": {"address": "192.168.0.12", "port":10010},
                "sync": {"address": "192.168.0.12", "port":10020},
                "system": {"address": "192.168.0.12", "port":10040},
                "transaction": {"address": "192.168.0.12", "port":10001},
                "sql": {"address": "192.168.0.12", "port":20001}
            }
        ]
    }
}

Node definition file (gs_node.json):
{
    "transaction": {
        "serviceAddress": "192.168.0.10",
        "servicePort": 10001
    },
    "sql": {
        "serviceAddress": "192.168.0.10",
        "servicePort": 20001
    }
}

Despite following these steps, the connection fails with an error indicating that the node cannot be reached. What am I missing or doing wrong?
Additional Information:

I'm running GridDB Community Edition.
The ports are open and accessible.
The nodes are correctly started and joined in the cluster.


Add the full error to the question.

You wrote (in your question): Added the JDBC driver file to the class path That is not how you add the JDBC driver to the classpath, that was how you register the JDBC driver with DriverManager, however that is no longer required. You also wrote: Configured the connection URL I see no URL in the code snippet. I see [database] connection properties.
